# JQuery - Image Fade w/ Php Variables

Tags: php, jquery, fade

I have thumbnail images below a larger image.  The thumbnails, when clicked, need to fade out the current large image, and fade in the thumbnail's large image.  All the images and theumbnails are being pulled from the database.

Whats the best way to go about doing this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.thumbnail').live('click', function(){
        var self = this;
        $('#hero img').fadeOut(function(){
            $('#hero img').attr('src', self.src.replace('50x50', '572x362')).fadeIn();
        });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the client side, using jQuery, would look something like:

```
$('.thumbnail').live('click', function(ev){
   ev.preventDefault();
   var self = this;
   $('.largeImage').fadeOut(function(){
      $('.largeImage').attr('src', self.src.replace(/_sm/, '_lg')).fadeIn();
   });
});
```

Your PHP then just generates the markup with `<img class="thumbnail" src="some_img_sm.jpg">` and some div `<img class="largeImage">`

Comment: sorry, i should have been more specific...the image src will be coming from Php.  So how would I do that?

Comment: get your data from your database into a php array, loop it and `echo "<img src=\"$imgSrc\">";` for each entry (sorry, I'd give you more but haven't touched PHP in about 5 years.

Comment: that worked, but the only thing is, the page automatically scrolls back to the top after the function executes, probably cause the image disapears for a second, and then reappears.  Anything I can do about this?

Comment: oh, add ev (for event) in the function definition: `function(ev){` and add this in the function: `ev.preventDefault();`

Comment: hm, im not quite sure where to put that.  Everywhere I've tried doesn't work.  I've edited my post above and put the code Im using

Comment: yeah, that still didn't work for me.  The page still re-scrolls to the top / takes the element out of the flow briefly

Comment: any other ideas on keeping the image in the flow?